# Listening to changes from multiple couchdb databases with a single node process

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I have multiple databases and I want to create a node module to listen to changes within then.

Is it possible to have a single node process listening to the changes feed from more than one couchdb database?

Or should each database have a separate node process listening for changes individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you can listen for changes from multiple feeds. An easy way is with the `follow` module here: https://github.com/iriscouch/follow. Just set up multiple listeners with the same callback (or different callbacks if you want to do different things with the changes coming from different sources).

Comment: What if the database was created dynamically after the process had started. Is it possible to listen to changes from all databases?

Comment: Well, you could have a listener factory that ingests database addresses as they appear and then attaches listeners to them. This would require either exporting an eventemitter or other interface from your factory or building some kind of polling into the factory itself.

Comment: Thank you, thats a really helpful suggestion